# Django ---models Object operation

Tags: python, django, django-models

I create a app named article and a class which is Article and migrate it to the models successfully. Class Article is coded as below:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)     #Blog Name
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = True)  #Blog Flag

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Then I enter in the manage shell and do some database operations:

```
>>>from article.models import Article

>>>Article.objects.create(title = 'Hello, Jammy', category = 'Blog') # Adding first element to database

>>>Article.objects.create(title = 'Programming methods', category = 'Learning') #Add second element to database

>>>foo = Article.objects.get(id = 1)
```

**Now what's interesting is :**

```
>>>foo.category = 'Test1'
>>>foo.category
u'Test1'
>>>Article.objects.get(id = 1)
u'Blog'
```

So why does the Article.objects.get(id = 1) value still be u'Blog' not u'Test1'? The object foo is a copy of original?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting the `category` model field value, *you have not saved the model*. Call [`.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save):

```
foo.save()
```

In other words, `foo` Django model instance was updated, but the changes were not reflected in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Alecxe. BTW, can you recommend a classic book or books about django development for me? Since I a fresher in python area, exactly in software development area, I have practiced some skills about the python basic programming like data analysis, socket network programming,etc.  Now I am learning about web development and really like the django framework for its clear.